# How to pass parameters to GUIPlugin for gzclient

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I need to run a separate node with Gazebo client like this:

```
<node name="gui_w_plugin" pkg="ros_gazebo" type="gzclient" args="--gui-client-plugin libgui_plugin.so"/>
```

However I was not able to pass any arguments to the plugin. I was also not able to find much documentation to GUIPlugin (but very brief API description).

Do you have an idea, how to:

1. pass arguments to plugin, so I can use tem in C++ plugin definition (either constructor or Load())?
2. start gazebo client other way, so I can use SDF parameters or other means?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26526/how-to-pass-parameters-to-guiplugin-for-gzclient/) by [m.bahno](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29530/m.bahno/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In the end, I used kind of workaround to pass arguments via local ROS parameter. However, I don't think this is the best way and I would find the most elegant way to be able to specify the sdf parameters even with node call.

---

Originally posted by [m.bahno](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29530/m.bahno/) with karma: 13 on 2021-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0